# Is eventual Consistency possible in case of Master - Master Configuration -

Tags: mongodb, distributed-computing, distributed, distributed-transactions, database

Is eventual Consistency possible in case of Master - Master Configuration.
i.e if their are more than one master to accept writes then we can always have conflicting writes in case of eventual consistency.

for example :  two master writing two user profile with same email id. 
In case of an eventual consistent system both masters may be able to successfully commit two user-profile with same email id - which is actual an inconsistent system

Comment: There will always be a delay between machines, laws of physics dictate that you cannot talk to two machines in sequence at the same time. If you write to both of them at the same time then: why? There is no performance benefit from that and in fact you will lose performance due to having to wait for two distinct networks instead of one

Comment: It's unclear what exactly what you're after for an answer. It's possible - the hard part is defining consistency in a way that the masters can enforce with each other. It can be done, e.g., trivially by a rule like "master 1 is always right", which would reduce master-master to something like master-slave.

Comment: Why the mongodb tag? It doesn't provide master-master configurations, only primary-secondary (replication) or one authoritative shard (sharding). There are quite some systems allowing writes on different nodes with eventual consistency — they will normally provide some conflict resolution (vector clocks, merging, last-write wins,...)

Comment: @falcon Does my answer help ? If yes then please accept it otherwise ask away if anything is unclear

Answer (score 1):

One: Locks are taken up before writing to the database or a cache.

Two: If the locks are taken up at the same time then there are further two more ways to resolve.

- Either an election is made among the two operations and one is elected whereas the other operation is rejected to the client and with it is returned the new value.
- Or distributed servers allow you to write a **conflict resolution** code and be deployed at the server, and is executed when this happens.

Usually topologies don't work that way, they distribute writes and there is a master and slave concept in a master master configurations as well. :)

Speaking theoretical of course.